# Looking for gps tracker for my dog

Tags: dogs, gps

Looking for the gps tracker for my dog.

Must be waterproof and should have the notification feature that alerts when my dog leaves or enters the home. Also would be good if it has a feature that allows me to talk to him through my phone.

The problem is I live in Georgia Tbilisi(Not USA) which means most of GPS I found does not seem like to work here. I guess I am gonna need it with GSM functionality. Any idea ?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Giving tips for products is out of scope of this site. But if you edit your question into "What special need does a GPS pet tracker have for Georgia" kind of general question, you may have a chance.

Comment: a gps tracker that can record or transmit sound might not be legal in many parts of the world.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a request for a product recommendation